# How do I change background and thickness of Android progress bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I need to create a progress drawable that will behave exactly like the standard one, but will also have a background and a different thickness.

In the screenshot below, you can see that it has a different thickness and an extra ring in the background.

It would be best if I could change the thickness and the color of the background ring programmatically.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: check out https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Progress-Bar-Custom-View

Comment: so, custom view is the only option and there is no way to override anything is the standard progress bar?

Comment: Even if I'm implementing a custom view, I'd like it to be a subclass of `ProgressBar`, so that I will not have to declare all the attributes of standard progress bar again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the best way to customize standard Android's progress widget is to write a custom progress drawable.

To implement indeterminate progress one can create a custom `Drawable` that implements `Animatable` interface. `ProgressBar` widget will automatically start the animation once `isIndeterminate` property is set to `true`.

The idea is taken from the library: https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

When `isIndeterminate` property equals to `false`, ProgressBar uses different drawable. When the progress value is set, it calls drawable's "setLevel()" method. Following the same idea of custom drawable, one can implement `onLevelChanged()` method, and update drawable state in it to reflect current progress.